# Powershell Here-String line breaks not working with output file

Tags: powershell

I have several hundred lines of text defined in a varibale as here-string:

```
$outputText = @"
Line1
Line2
Line3
And so on...
"@
```

If I print the `$outputText` on screen, it's showing properly:

```
PS > $outputText
Line1
Line2
Line3
And so on...
PS >
```

However, when I try to output it to a file in any way I can figure, I always lose the line breaks and the file looks like this:

```
Line1Line2Line3And so on...
```

I've tried to following:

```
$outputText | Set-Content file.txt
Add-Content file.txt -Value $outputText
Out-File -InputObject $outputText file.txt
```

If I add `'r'n` (with proper ticks) at the end of each line, the visible output has extra line break between each line but the output file is showing each line correctly. However, putting the return carriage and new line escapes after each of the several hundred lines is not really an option.

How would I be able to properly output the line breaks in a file easier or define the multi-line string some other way so the line breaks would work without complicated escape characters or such?

Comment: Unsure. The Multiline string works perfectly fine for me and I get the lines well defined in file.txt.   (Tested on Powershell 5.1 / Windows 10) Your example worked as intended in my case.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue neither. Also, your *proper* output shows `PS >` prompt before each line, that shouldn't be the case. What is your environment?

Comment: @JanneTuukkanen You're right, I fixed the proper output code block. I'm using Windows 10 with PowerShell 5.1, but I can reproduce the problem exactly the same way with Windows Server 2012 R2 using PowerShell 4.0 in the actual environment I'm working in.

Comment: How are you viewing the "bad" data? Is that from notepad? Reading the file back in via `Get-Content`. I would be using a hexeditor at this point to see what is actually in that string.

Comment: Yes, Notepad mainly to test. The lines are applied to .css and .js files and when viewing them as a source code via browser the line breaks are broken as well.

Comment: This is true even with multi-line strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A here string puts the text in **ONE** string, lines delimited with a LF/0xA.

```
$outputText = @"
Line1
Line2
Line3
And so on...
"@
$outputText | Format-Hex
```

---

```
           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   4C 69 6E 65 31 0A 4C 69 6E 65 32 0A 4C 69 6E 65  Line1.Line2.Line
00000010   33 0A 41 6E 64 20 73 6F 20 6F 6E 2E 2E 2E 0D 0A  3.And so on.....
```

In contrast splitting the string:

```
$outputText = @"
Line1
Line2
Line3
And so on...
"@ -split '\n'  # or -split "`n"

$outputText | Set-Content file1.txt
Out-File -InputObject $outputText file2.txt

1..2|%{(Get-Content ".\file$_.txt" -raw) | Format-Hex}
```

---

```
           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   4C 69 6E 65 31 0D 0A 4C 69 6E 65 32 0D 0A 4C 69  Line1..Line2..Li
00000010   6E 65 33 0D 0A 41 6E 64 20 73 6F 20 6F 6E 2E 2E  ne3..And so on..
00000020   2E 0D 0A                                         ...


           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   4C 69 6E 65 31 0D 0A 4C 69 6E 65 32 0D 0A 4C 69  Line1..Line2..Li
00000010   6E 65 33 0D 0A 41 6E 64 20 73 6F 20 6F 6E 2E 2E  ne3..And so on..
00000020   2E 0D 0A                                         ...
```

Other things possibly influencing the output (not here),

- the [automatic_variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1) `$OFS`
- `$OutputEncoding`
- `[System.Environment]::NewLine`

---

```
> $OutputEncoding


IsSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : us-ascii
EncodingName      : US-ASCII
HeaderName        : us-ascii
WebName           : us-ascii
WindowsCodePage   : 1252
IsBrowserDisplay  : False
IsBrowserSave     : False
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 20127
```

**PS**: running the 2nd script in VSCode returned a 0D/0D/0A sequence, had to use `-split '\r\n'`

Comment: I couldn't find the root cause of this, but your proposed solution works properly even on a computer that has no described problematic behavior, thank you!

Comment: It is the newline style of the enclosing script file that determines whether here-strings have CRLF or LF-only newlines. `$OFS` only comes into play if you use arrays with string expansion (inside double-quoted strings), which is not the case here.

Comment: `[System.Environment]::NewLine` settings are identical between a computer where it doesn't work and where it does work, what do you mean?

Comment: @lapingultah: My comment doesn't explain your symptom; I was merely pointing out that LotPings' statement that `lines [are] delimited with a LF/0xA` is not always true, because the type of newline sequence used depends on the enclosing script file, which in turn is not necessarily the same as   `[System.Environment]::NewLine`, depending on the editor that created the script file. As an aside: Since I'm not the owner of this answer, you must @-mention me to be notified of follow-up comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is true with multi line strings too.  Another way to do it.  Turn unix text (`n) into windows text (`r`n).

```
$outputtext = @"
Line1
Line2
Line3
And so on...
"@ -replace "`n","`r`n"
```

Doublecheck it:

```
$outputtext -replace '\n','\n' -replace '\r','\r'

Line1\r\nLine2\r\nLine3\r\nAnd so on...
```

The first argument of -replace can use either the backslash or backquote notation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$FilePath = YourOutputFilePath
$InputString = 'This is my text with new lines.
It would be nice to have new lines in my text file output.
Also, to preserve this formatting.'   
Out-File -FilePath $FilePath -InputObject $InputString.Replace("`n", "`r`n") -Encoding unicode -Append -Force
```

This worked well for me.