# Strings and here document have UNIX line endings on Windows

Tags: powershell, string-literals, line-endings, multilinestring, herestring

Both here documents and strings are using UNIX 0x0A line endings on Windows instead of 0x0D0A. How can I get them to be Windows line endings?

```
PS C:\> $s = @"
>> now
>> is
>> the
>> "@
PS C:\> $s
now
is
the
PS C:\> $s | Format-Hex

   Label: String (System.String) <7B93DCA4>

          Offset Bytes                                           Ascii
                 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
          ------ ----------------------------------------------- -----
0000000000000000 6E 6F 77 0A 69 73 0A 74 68 65                   now�is�the

PS C:\> $s2 = "
>> Now
>> is
>> the
>> "
PS C:\> $s2

Now
is
the

PS C:\> $s2 | Format-Hex

   Label: String (System.String) <33E42D9F>

          Offset Bytes                                           Ascii
                 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
          ------ ----------------------------------------------- -----
0000000000000000 0A 4E 6F 77 0A 69 73 0A 74 68 65 0A             �Now�is�the�

PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.3.7
```

Comment: ``-replace '(?<!\r)\n', "`r`n"``. Also, has been asked before it seems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54129708/powershell-here-string-line-breaks-not-working-with-output-file

Answer (score 2):

**[Your own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77261417/45375) is probably the best approach**, as it ensures use of the platform-appropriate newline format on all supported platforms.

Let me complement it with **background information**.

When **defining *multiline* string literals** in PowerShell (both [regular string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules) and their [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) variants):

- ***inside a script file*** (`.ps1`, `.psm1`), PowerShell uses the **same newline format as the *enclosing file***.
- ***interactively*** - perhaps surprisingly - PowerShell ***invariably* use LF-only newlines** (`` "`n" `` in PowerShell), on *all* supported  platforms.

In other words, for use in *scripts*:

- If you want either CRLF (Windows-format, `` "`r`n" ``) or LF-only (Unix-format, `` "`n" ``) newlines in multiline string literals, *save your script file in that format*.
- For *cross-platform* scripts, use your `-replace` solution.

  - It will hardly matter in practice, but if you want to avoid unnecessary replacements, you can use the following approach:

    - Save your script with LF-only newlines.
    - Perform a replacement only if necessary, which can then be a *literal* replacement, via `.Replace()`:

      ```
      if ($env:OS -eq 'Windows_NT') { 
        $multiLineStr = $multiLineStr.Replace("`n", "`r`n") 
      }
      ```

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking that what is generally the goal is to get the current platform specific newline sequence used. To accomplish this, I think I will use:

```
-replace '(?<!\r)\n', [Environment]::NewLine
```

This seems to be working on Windows, wsl, and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways of doing this:

You can use [dos2unix](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix/).

Or you can use a regex.

There are multiple regex syntaxes but for powershell it is just  `` -replace '(?<!\r)\n', "`r`n" ``

Comment: Zoey, I do not think there is a `dos2unix` on Windows and PowerShell without installing some other kit. Also, The replacement string probably should not use REVERSE SOLIDUS (backslash) characters.